# Stop bumping old questions because it's frustrating

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-user, bump

The Stack Overflow software sometimes puts years old questions into the homepage stream in order to get them finally answered. This is a totally honorable approach because the idea of Stack Overflow is to create long lasting artifacts that help many.

Unfortunately, it feels like talking to a wall.

It is really frustrating to interact with such a question (e.g. post a comment or an answer) and nobody's there who cares. Many of these questions are one-off questions that only help the OP. He no longer cares after months and years.

I never interact with them except when I don't notice. Then I notice after posting something that I essentially have become public laughing stock for doing something that useless :)

I bet it's awkward to the OP as well to see that someone invested effort to help with a completely obsolete issue. He can either do nothing (rude) or add a comment that this is no longer relevant which is awkward. Or, he adds a false accept mark (false because he can probably no longer validate the answer).

Question to other users: How often do you *not* regret answering such a question if you did not notice this beforehand?

Feature request: Please stop bumping questions, or at least revise the heuristic used to select them.

Comment: i've never noticed it for a question that i actually *wanted* to answer. Often times there's a good reason such questions went unanswered.

Comment: @KevinB so the feature is useless to you and should be removed as well. Wasted your time. Maybe I'm hit often because I answer a lot of debugging style questions.

Comment: Can't mark as a duplicate, since it's on Meta-SE, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99672/141629

Comment: @PaulRoub kind of duplicate but after 4 years a new discussion is warranted. Also Stack Overflow might be relevant context as opposed to the whole SE network.

Comment: Can maybe someone speak up who actively likes this feature? Can't imagine a reason given how bad it works.

Comment: *"but after 4 years a new discussion is warranted"* (had to pause and note the irony here) :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, sure, the feature does tend to get it wrong a lot of times.  It is just a machine and it can't tell that the *real* problem with the Q+A is that the questioner just left the building without accepting an answer.  That's a jackass problem, not a machine problem and not your problem and not our problem.

But it is the kind of problem that many SO users rarely have to deal with.  The harder to solve problem for the machine is that it just doesn't know what kind of questions to show you.  You don't have enough history to let it pick the right ones.  Your 18 posts are not enough by a long shot.  It needs at least an order of magnitude more.  Or two.

It will get better when you give it a chance to learn.  Start doing so by editing your profile, pick your favorite and ignored tags first.  Gives the machine a big leg up to getting it right.  Meanwhile, pay attention.  Always good to pay attention.

Comment: What's your personal experience with this? We have a 100k rep guy at the office and he actually initiated the conversation at the office. We have many SO users there.

Comment: I don't get them very often and usually pay attention enough to skip them.  The view counter is always high and Community tends to be the last user that touched it so it is easy enough to see.  Hi-rep users have another annoyance, having to deal with a bozo that edited dozens of posts only to change a [tag] and you have to review them all.  Ugh.

Comment: OK, so the feature doesn't work for you and you would be better off if it did not exist.

Comment: @boot4life are you trying to actually have a thoughtful discussion or are you just here to reaffirm your opinions? Because I don't think that was what he said.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest please explain. Why would he skip those questions if they were useful for him? I conclude that he does not want to see them.

Answer (score 14):

I interact with them and I like it!

If it has a bad title, I go and fix it (and other things along the way).

If it's interesting, I go and read it and vote up everything that has good quality  and teaches me something (could be one of your answers), and downvote/flag the weird stuff.

Here's an [Userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/userscripts?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=50) that will get rid of all that pesky Community posts on the frontpage for you:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        (SO) Bye bye, Community
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/
// ==/UserScript==

$('a[href="/users/-1/community"]').each(function() {
    $(this).parents(".question-summary.narrow").remove()
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If the post has serious problems with it then *address those problems*.  Downvote the post if it's not a quality post; vote to close it if it merits closure, etc.  Apparently the post wasn't effectively moderated the first time around.  Take this opportunity to remedy that.

Comment: The most serious problem is that it's what previously was called "too narrow" and the guy is gone. He does not care anymore. Can't fix that. Bury the question, don't rub it in peoples faces.

Comment: @boot4life Burying an unanswered question on the site does no one any good and could be said to lower the overall quality of the site.

Comment: @boot4life Whether or not the OP is interested is irrelevant.  SO isn't a place to answer questions for just one person.  Either it's a valuable question that someone else could find useful (whether that someone is the OP or not), in which case there's no problem, either answer it or move on, or it's not, and you can moderate the post appropriately to indicate that.

Comment: @Servy since "too narrow" is no longer valid these questions are totally on topic although they will help only one person. There is nothing to edit or improve. Also, my "talking to a wall" point still stands. See what Hans does: he walks away systematically.

Comment: @boot4life You think that every single question ever bumped by Community will never merit closure for any reason?  Like I said.  If the post merits closure, close it.  If it's low quality, downvote it.  If it's a good question, answer it.  Do exactly the same thing that you'd do for any new question.

Comment: @boot4life That's not actually what Hans said.  You're putting words in his mouth.  He, like most people, words hard to only even *look at* questions that seem interesting.  For most people the vast majority of questions aren't even worth opening up, as the info shown on the title page often has enough to indicate that a given question isn't interesting enough to merit reading.  He says that very few of these questions even get looked at by him to begin with, not that he looks at a lot of them and then has to walk away because of problems he sees.

Comment: @boot4life As to your "talking to a wall" point, as I already said, SO isn't about answering questions just for the OP.  You should be treating questions identically whether the OP is active or inactive.  Either the question is a good question *for the whole world*, or it's not.  If the OP is the only person in the world who would care if the question is answered then *you shouldn't be answering the question even if they are active*, so it shouldn't matter if they're still around.

Comment: "[I] usually pay attention enough to skip them" is what he said. I interpret that to mean "If I don't skip them it's because I failed to pay enough attention which fortunately is rare".; I do understand your position that the right thing to do is to not care about age. I think that many users do care though because they ultimately are here to have fun. Anyway, all is said on this topic and we know where we disagree.

Answer (score 6):

First, you can already hide old questions using [the 'created' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in search.

Second, SO has to give people who have improved their questions a chance to be seen because that's literally the only way to get out of a question ban. How is it fair to tell users that the only way to fix things is to get people to up vote their questions and then tell them there's no way to get their question back on the front page?

> I never interact with them except when I don't notice. Then I notice
>   after posting something that I essentially have become public laughing
>   stock for doing something that useless :)

No one here would laugh at someone for answering an old, unanswered question. Why would they? There's no policy or convention against answering old questions. In fact, there are two badges that you can earn for answering an old question and getting a positive score on it.

Given the frequency of people asking how they can get new answers to old questions, I don't understand what you have against this.

> I bet it's awkward to the OP as well to see that someone invested
>   effort to help with a completely obsolete issue. He can either do
>   nothing (rude)...

OK, I can see why this would be frustrating but requiring the OP to reply to every comment/post would be more futile than requiring people to comment when voting.

> or add a comment that this is no longer relevant which is awkward.

There is a close reason for this: *This question was caused by a problem **that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.*

> Or, he adds a false accept mark (false because he can probably no longer validate the answer).

There is no reason to assume this. 1) What would the OP get out of lying about your answer being correct? 2) Presumably, you were able to reproduce it and fix it with your solution, so why wouldn't the OP be able to?

Comment: I have nothing against answering "reusable" questions where a contribution is made to the web that other people need ("how I can [general thing]?"). What's pointless, though, and common is a question like "Here is a debugging problem, I have shown effort and research so it's on topic!". Those are one-off and become irrelevant within days.

Comment: Regarding the false mark, I'm not saying this is being done. Saying that if it was done it would be a false mark so it's not a good course of action. He also would get +2 rep... what ever that's worth to him. "you were able to reproduce it and fix it". That's not how most questions are answered. Usually, you answer from experience and don't test stuff. At least that's how I think all the top guys plus me work.