# Serial(?) editing spree of old question with pandas/python - adding dataframe tag to them

Tags: discussion, edits

I had <strike>4 or 5</strike> 3 edit reviews by the same user who added [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) to questions already containing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas).

I read on meta:

- [Stop bumping old questions because it's frustrating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308058/stop-bumping-old-questions-because-its-frustrating/308116#308116) (-21)
- [Is bumping old questions allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125965/is-bumping-old-questions-allowed)
  (+17)
- [Is it encouraged to bump (update) old answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357400/is-it-encouraged-to-bump-update-old-answers) (+27)

I do not quite get the value of adding a tag to questions that are 3+years old. I checked one user and he was last seen 3y ago...

I left the editor-user a message:

> Adding tags to 3.5 year old question is not a good idea - the addition of that tag does not lead to more results - but it bumps the
>   question into view again - I just reviewed 2 old questions where you
>   added the dataframe tag - both old. I am not sure why you did so - I
>   hope not for the rep from editing ... bumping old stuff is not nice.
>   The poster of this question was last seen on Jan 2015 - this is not
>   helping anyone. If you have an answer or can seriously improve a
>   question with chances to be answered - go ahead. But adding "datframe"
>   to "python + pandas" does *nothing*.

Is there some kind of saveguard against rep-farming by mass-editing tags to year old stuff?

Comment: Do you happen to have one of those completed reviews handy?  If all the editor is doing is adding tags *and* that's getting approved, I'm sure that the people approving those edits should probably take a break.

Comment: @Makoto I approved one and refuted the others. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22000055  and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22000703 - the one I approved was from this week though - not 3y old

Comment: I was tempted to reject these when I saw them, but let several slide because the [`pandas` usage guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info) explicitly demands that all `pandas` questions also be tagged either `dataframe` or `series`. I don't know much about pandas, but could see that the questions involved dataframes, and assumed that that usage guidance had been thoughtfully considered by the pandas community on SO and that adding such tags provided some meaningful benefit to them such that these edits were worth making, even with the need for review. Perhaps I made the wrong call.

Comment: @Makoto I did a search for after seeing some of these, because I thought I recalled once reading guidance that tag-only edits should be rejected out of hand, but I couldn't find it. Was I imagining it, or do we have such a policy? If so, could you point me to it?

Comment: @MarkAmery:  I recall it too but am in no position to search for it right now.  Maybe it's still on Uber-Meta?

Comment: I don't understand the suggestion of adding dataframe and series to all pandas questions *at all*. IMO this just dilutes tags that people may be searching for another reason. Series is a mathematical term, and dataframes are something shared across more than one programming language (although maybe their functionality is similar enough to warrant looking at R solutions for Pandas questions). If this were implemented, searching for "series" would bring up questions about a particular object from a particular library from a particular language, which seems totally wrong to me.

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is obvious to some but I'll put it out there so that we are on the same page.  Pandas is a library whose main object is a `DataFrame`.  The anatomy of this `DataFrame` consists of `Series` and `Index` objects.  That said, there are ***MANY*** other elements/dimensions/nuances of Pandas that have deserving questions.  Bottom line is Pandas is ***NOT*** synonymous with `DataFrame`.  If such guidance exists, I strongly disagree with it.

This post does not need the `DataFrame` tag as it is specific to the `Timestamp` object.  I just rolled it back.

[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703720/2336654)

Comment: Additionally, Pandas is not the only context for a dataframe. R's main tabular data structure is *also* a dataframe. Generally both libs are able to do many similar things on dataframes, so if it's a question about filtering, or grouping, or some operation that a dataframe should support, the tag `dataframe` makes sense as the general approach to a solution may be shared over languages.

Comment: Agreed.  In fact Pandas was created to give Python functionality similar to R's dataframe.

Comment: Looks like revision 12 was the one that added the guidance for `dataframe`/`series` to be added to every Pandas question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6469623/revisions. If that's bad guidance, want to 1) remove it from the excerpt and 2) poke the user who added it to ask them why?

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed that paragraph from the excerpt, and @-notified the user who added the guidance suggesting that they weigh in on this Meta thread.

Answer (score -1):

As the user who added the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag usage guidance of tagging the question with a [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) if it was necessary, I thought it would be good to weigh in.

This guidance was partially directed towards OPs writing pandas posts. I am given to believe that users coming from a Google Search looking for a solution to their problem typically either enter search terms including "pandas dataframe", or including "python dataframe". This is based on circumstantial evidence from questions that include [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) but miss [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), and from my own experience having done so. Since Google concatenates the tags to the title when indexing the page, it will be easier to find these questions were someone to enter such a search term.

Regarding the edits, I think they would've been fine as part of larger, more substantial edits. But they weren't, so rejecting them would have been my move as well. Solely editing question tags in is something only a user who has editing privilege should do.

Comment: I question the factual premises behind this. Google doesn't add tags to the title. Rather, *Stack Overflow* adds *one* tag to the page title - namely, the most popular one that doesn't already naturally appear in the title. Unless the asker has used both of the words "Python" and "Pandas" in their title, additionally adding the `dataframe` tag isn't going to change the title, and so seems unlikely to have any SEO impact either.

Comment: @MarkAmery Is that so? I see... I'm sorry about that. While my intentions came from a good place, I can see how I might've botched this one. My bad.

Comment: Well, it sounds like we've now at least got unanimous agreement that the guidance can stay dead, then. So, progress. :)